# Single Letter Temperature Coefficient for Capacitors?

Tags: ceramic, temperature-coefficient

A certain [parts supplier](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ceramic-capacitors/60) offers ceramic capacitors with temperature coefficients (tempcos) of single letters -- `A`, `E`, and so on -- but I cannot find any information on what these letters specify.  (The example below suggests that `E` is equivalent to `Y5U`.)

[image: DigiKey search example]

By looking into datasheets of parts with these tempcos ([example](https://product.tdk.com/en/system/files?file=dam/doc/product/capacitor/ceramic/lead-disc/catalog/leaddisc_commercial_cs45_en.pdf)), they seem to be more of a tolerance over temperature instead of a tempo code such as `X7R` or `Y5V`.

[image: Capacitor datasheet example]

Is there a specific phrase/term for which I should be searching, or does anyone have any reference material?

Answer (score 0):

That is because Class II and Class III dielectrics have such a high tolerance that you really can't consider it as a tempco.

In X7R and Y5V the R and V are the tolerance or tempco.

With Class I dielectrics such as C0G, they are much more stable so the C0 is the tempco code and multiplier (here basically 0 ppm/°C) and G is the tolerance for tempco, in ppm/°C.

In your example, the manufacturer tolerance code E matches the U on a Y5U capacitor. And the V of Y5V is actually slightly better than manufacturer tolerance code F.